# readIO parse error haskell, this close

Tags: haskell

So I've been enjoying this challenging language, I am currently working on an assignment for school.

This is what it says: I need to prompt the user for a list of numbers, then display the average of the list , I am so close to figuring it out. However I get this weird parse error:

```
"Exception: user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse)"
```

Here is my code:

```
module Main (listM', diginums', getList, main) where 

import System.IO     
import Data.List

diginums' = []
listM' = [1, 2, 3]
average' = (sum diginums') / (fromIntegral (length diginums'))
getList :: IO [Double]
getList = readLn

main = do
      putStrLn "Please enter a few numbers" 
      diginums' <- getList
      putStrLn $ show average'
```

Terminal Prompts : `Enter a few #'s`

I Enter : `123`

```
ERROR : Exception: user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse)
```

I know my functions are working correctly to calculate the average. Now I think my problem is that when I take in the list of numbers from the user, I don't correctly parse them to type `Double` for my average function.

Comment: Why should we ignore indentation? You can make the indentation look correct here, which will save a lot of grief.

Comment: lol i try to make it correct but everytime i click submit answer my browser seems to ruin the correct indentation from the textpad ...  Sorry !

Comment: While we're talking about indentation: make sure you use spaces instead of (real) tabs. Layout which looks good might be totally wrong because GHC interprets tab as 8 spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type signature says that

```
getList :: IO [Double]
getList = readLn
```

reads a list of `Double`s, that means it expects input of the form

```
[123, 456.789, 1011.12e13]
```

but you gave it what could be read as a single number, `"123"`. Thus the `read` fails, the input couldn't be parsed as a `[Double]`.

If you want to parse input in a different form, not as syntactically correct Haskell values, for example as a space-separated list of numbers, you can't use `readLn`, but have to write a parser for the desired format yourself. For the mentioned space-separated list of numbers, that is very easy, e.g

```
getList :: IO [Double]
getList = do
    input <- getLine
    let nums = words input
    return $ map read nums
```

If you want to get the list in the form of numbers each on its own line, ended by an empty line, you'd use a recursion with an accumulator,

```
getList :: IO [Double]
getList = completeList []

completeList :: [Double] -> IO [Double]
completeList acc = do
    line <- getLine
    if null line
        then return (reverse acc)
        else completeList (read line : acc)
```

Parsers for more complicated or less rigid formats would be harder to write.

When the parsing is fixed, you run into the problem that you haven't yet got used to the fact that values are immutable.

```
diginums' = []
listM' = [1, 2, 3]
average' = (sum diginums') / (fromIntegral (length diginums'))
```

defines three values, the `Double` value `average'` is defined in terms of the empty list `diginums'`, hence its value is

```
sum diginums' / fromIntegral (length diginums') = 0 / 0
```

which is a `NaN`.

What you need is a function that computes the average of a list of `Double`s, and apply that to the entered list in `main`.

```
average :: [Double] -> Double
average xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)

main = do
    putStrLn "Please enter a few numbers" 
    numbers <- getList
    print $ average numbers
```

Comment: Just tried it out, No Luck 

I entered : [123, 456.789] #i had to add the brackets :S weird
NO ERROR but result is : NaN

Comment: Yes, for `readLn`, you need the brackets, they're part of the syntax. As for the result, your top-level value `average'` is a `NaN`, since it's `0/0`, as `diginums'` is an empty list. The local name in `main` that you bind the read list to is completely unrelated.

Comment: it's incredible your knownledge in haskel , i actually learned a lot from your explaination , Thank You for your help i still have a long way but im sure i can get to be as good as you ! Thanks Again !

Answer (score 3):

There are no mutable variables in Haskell, but it looks like you are trying to initialise `diginums'` as an empty list and then populate it with `getList`.

Instead, maybe you want to pass the list of numbers to `average'` as an argument, something like:

```
module Main (getList, main) where

import System.IO
import Data.List


average' ds = (sum ds) / (fromIntegral (length ds))
getList :: IO [Double]
getList = readLn

main = do
      putStrLn "Please enter a few numbers"
      diginums' <- getList
      putStrLn $ show $ average' diginums'
```

Also, as Daniel said, you need to input using Haskell literal List syntax, given the way you've coded it.